# render and save scen with three.js int png or canvas BitMap

Tags: three.js, save, png, render, scene

I'm interesting to know if and how three.js can be applied to rendered 2d Sprites and use in my web page

my aim is to render a scene (in a div for example) and save it as a png (similar to a 3d programme); no need to save a frame of my animation (as I see, examples are provided in forums)

can anyone provide a simple example of a top to end creation and save of a static scene?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you be able to describe what you have done so far more in detail? If you could provide your code and reproducible sample, you are likely to receive more support. I hope you can revise your question. :)

Comment: You can use the `toDataURL()` function on any canvas and as three.js scenes are rendered into a canvas, I don't see why it would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can save it as a png. Following function takes the currently rendered output, creates a new image and adds it to the page (you can also download the image if you want, see commented section).

```
   function copyCanvas() {
        imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();

        // create a new image and add to the document
        imgNode = document.createElement("img");
        imgNode.src = imgData;
        document.body.appendChild(imgNode);

//        alternative way, which downloads the image 
//        var link = document.createElement("a");
//        link.download = 'capture.png';
//        link.href = imgData;
//        link.click();
    }
```

A complete example can be found here:
https://github.com/josdirksen/threejs-cookbook/blob/master/06-particles-postprocessing/06.09-save-webgl-output.html